# Configure VPN on windows server 2012 and be able to access on the internet

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

in my company, we had only one branch and until recntly my boss told me we wil be expanding and all branches we use our specific network application. Now i have demonstrated with virtual machines how the connection will be possible and even presented, now my issue is in the real life, how will my windows sever which is my VPN server be talked to on the internet? to connect to the server over internet i will need internet address that links me directly to the server, is that communication the ISP work or how should i go about it?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Uhm... I don't understand what "is that communication the ISP work" means, but in principle yes, the VPN connection is established by connecting to the public IP of the server. Though ideally with two branches you would set up a site to site VPN. https://computer.howstuffworks.com/vpn4.htm

Comment: @Broco I meant like access to the server from the internet should be done by the ISP right?

Comment: Why would it? Your ISP just provides you with internet; routing, VPN and firewalls are your job as an admin.

Comment: @Broco thanks man and ur link is helpful... and lastly, id ADDS required for the VPN setup?

Comment: I don't even know what VPN software you are planning on using. Ideally you don't even use the Windows servers for it but your routers including the firewall. No offense, but since this is a professional setup, maybe get a professional company to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN has been traditionally handled by the end user using a firewall at both locations to create a site to site VPN. You can use a Sonicwall, Fortigate, Windows Server or similar to establish a VPN connection. You can also use a SDN provided by your ISP for example, you can use Comcast's ActiveCore SDN where the ISP provides not only internet access but also 'VPN' style connections between your sites. With an SDN you do not need any equipment at your site except your core switch and the ISP will take care of the rest. This is a nice option if you don't want to be responsible for a VPN connection.

[Comcast ActiveCore SDN](https://business.comcast.com/sdn)

[Fortigate Site to Site VPN](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/5.6.0/cookbook/281288/site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-with-two-fortigates)

[SonicWall VPN](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/vpn-configuring-site-to-site-vpn-using-the-quick-configuration-on-sonicos-enhanced/170505690888348/)